# How do I slice a string by characters in Python?

Tags: python

There is a string with one or more characters. I want to slice the list so that the adjoining same characters are in the same element. For example:

```
'a' -> ['a']
'abbbcc' -> ['a', 'bbb', 'cc']
'abcabc' -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

How do I make this in Python?

Comment: FYI, if you google "python group identical elements" or something similar you'll find plenty of recipes that would help you get started.

Answer (score 20):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'abccbba'

print([''.join(v) for _, v in groupby(s)])
# ['a', 'b', 'cc', 'bb', 'a']
```

Answer (score 8):

It can be achieved with [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re
s = 'aabccdd'
print([m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(\w)\1*", s)])
#['aa', 'b', 'cc', 'dd']
```

Answer (score 3):

Without any modules and using a `for` loop it can also be done in an interesting way:

```
l = []
str = "aabccc"
s = str[0]
for c in str[1:]:

    if (c != s[-1]):
        l.append(s)
        s = c
    else:
        s = s + c
l.append(s)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just one more alternative solution. You don't need any import for it in Python 2. In Python 3, you need to import from functools.

```
from functools import reduce   # In Python 3
s = 'aaabccdddddaa'
reduce(lambda x, y:x[:-1]+[x[-1]+y] if len(x)>0 and x[-1][-1]==y else x+[y], s, [])
```

Comment: Wow...this is as unreadable as it could get...

Answer (score 1):

```
t = input()
c = [t[0]]
for i in range(1, len(t)):
    if t[i] == c[-1][0]:
        c[-1] = c[-1] + t[i]
    else:
        c.append(t[i])
print(c)
```

Comment: Please add some text to make the answer more descriptive.